# Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"

Tags: 20.04, gtk

I was trying to open flameshot app in Ubuntu 20.04 and got this error

```
Gtk-Message: 21:47:04.722: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
```

I checked many other posts but nothing worked so far.
This error comes for some other apps too like copyq, knotes, not just flameshot.

Comment: Details needed. Do you really have official Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed? How flameshot were installed? Please also add output of  `dpkg -l | grep -i xapp` to the question by editing it.

Comment: Yes, I have Official Ubuntu 20.04 installed. Flameshot was installed from .deb file which was downloaded from developer's github page

Comment: This [log message \[is harmless and\] will go away the next time the xapp package is updated (probably 2.0.7)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263690)

Answer (score 22):

Installing `xapp` installs the missing modules and removes the warning

```
sudo apt install xapp
```

Pay attention that

> You need to install it with `apt`, not `snap`

Comment: Fail: `xapp is already the newest version (2.2.8-1)`

Comment: Well this may solve this for some, however it's probably some related issue, it happened to me when trying to open `gedit filename` - but gedit still opened and saving worked, but it was somehow unattached from terminal - which usually is bound to it

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package xapp`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue running Debian Bullseye.  Every time I launched a dialog  driven app from the terminal I got this error:

```
Gtk-Message: 09:28:30.670: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
```

I reinstalled `gir1.2-xapp-1.0`, which reinstalled dependencies. The error no longer appears.

Some of the dependencies were: `gist`, `inxi`, `libxapp1`, `tree`, `xapps-common`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked and the error no longer appears. And I installed libxapp-dev package too.

Comment: I installed both `gir1.2-xapp-1.0` and `libxapp-dev` but still getting the error. On Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @AtifAli Try installing these two packages if they are not already installed xapps-common, libxapp1 and python3-xapp.

Comment: @Subhash. all three are insatlled. Now th error is gone but I don't see any display after launching the app. This is the application I am trying to run, https://github.com/moritzgloeckl/overleaf-sync. I do not see a display when I run `ols login`

Comment: No success after the `gir1.2-xapp-1.0` re-installation. I have installed all these packages (xapps-common libxapp1 python3-xapp), but the error is still present.

Comment: On Debian 11 with Pyzo 4.11.2-1 on new Python 3.9.2 shell, `sudo apt install libxapp-dev` solved the issue.

Comment: on Debian 12 bullseye:
`# apt-get install libxapp-gtk3-module`

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu OS

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar
```

The below command should solve the warning.

```
sudo apt install xapp-sn-watcher libxapp-gtk3-module
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my case: Ubuntu 23.10: "sudo apt install --reinstall xapp-sn-watcher libxapp-gtk3-module" --> firefox ---> Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"